# Cosa significa "ardita" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia di chi fugge e di chi resta* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Da ragazzina mi ero immaginata che, oltre il rione, Napoli offrisse meraviglie. Il grattacielo della stazione centrale, per esempio, mi aveva colpita molto, decenni prima, per il suo ergersi piano dietro piano, uno scheletro di edificio che allora ci pareva altissimo, a lato dell’**ardita** stazione ferroviaria. Come mi sorprendevo, quando passavo per piazza Garibaldi: guarda quant’è alto, dicevo a Lila, a Carmen, a Pasquale, ad Ada, ad Antonio, a tutti i compagni di allora con i quali mi spingevo verso il mare, ai margini dei quartieri ricchi.

Malgrado abbia cercato il vocabolo "ardito" in alcuni dizionari, non riesco a capire il suo significato nel brano precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 3):

Qui [ardito](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/A/ardito.shtml) (coraggioso, intrepido, baldanzoso) viene usato in senso figurato:

> - fig. Innovatore, originale: *ipotesi ardita* (Hoepli)

- Lo stile di cotruzione della stazione era  o pareva insolita, originale agli occhi della scrittrice.

[Sistemi di costruzione](http://www.icpiazzagola.gov.it/siti/storiaromana/lavori/tecnichecostruttive.htm):

> - Opus latericium o lateritius: è il più utilizzato e famoso, che consiste nell'impilare mattoni di argilla cotta di varie dimensioni standard con leganti vari. ***Questo sistema è quello che ha reso possibile costruzioni ardite quali la Basilica di Massenzio*** con le sue tre enormi arcate, o anche il Colosseo e le mura Aureliane.

[image]

L'aggettivo [ardito](http://domenicosportelli.eu/tag/costruzioni-ardite/) viene anche usato in senso critico in riferimento a costruzioni esteticamente e strutturalmente discutibili:

> - / Viaggi / costruzioni ardite, ecomostri, Liguria di ponente.

Comment: Detto di una costruzione, “ardito” oltre che innovatore etc. mi dà anche l'idea di qualcosa che appunto “osa” molto, quasi che non si capisse come fa a stare in piedi: arcate enormi come la Basilica di Massenzio (rese possibili dal laterizio come spiegato), l'[“ardita pensilina”](http://www.fabriziomosconi.com/foto/foto/esquilino/big/stazione_termini01.jpg) – quasi un luogo comune – priva di sostegni della stazione Termini a Roma (resa possibile dal cemento armato) etc.

Comment: (Che è successo al tuo nick, Josh?)

Comment: @DaG - work in progress :), verrà modificato appena possibile.